# Vue API client no responde la peticion JSON

Tags: json, api, vue.js

Estoy haciendo una solicitud a una `API` con `Vue` para adaptarlo con `Rail`, pero cuando hago la impresión de los datos en pantalla me manda vació, este es la conexión a la `API`:

**main.js:**

```
var urlAPI = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

    new Vue({
      el: 'body',
      created: function() {
        this.consultaAPI();
      },

      data: {
        personas: []
      },
      methods: {
        consultaAPI: function() {
          this.$http.get(urlAPI)
        .then(function(respuesta) {
          this.personas = respuesta.data.results;
        });
    }
  },
  components: {
    'personas': {
      template: '#personas-template',
      props: ['lista']
    }
  }
});
```

Luego hago el despliegue en el html:

```
 <personas :lista="personas"></personas>
  <template id="personas-template">
    <ul v-for="persona in lista">
      <li>{{ persona.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </template>

  <pre>
  {{ $data | json}}
  </pre>
```

Y no manda la información cuando hago la inspección de los datos pro medio del navegador me manda lo siguiente.

[image: Captura]

Agradeceria si pudieran indicar me si estoy omitiendo algo.

Answer (score 0):

estas intentando registrar un componente, pero estas usando un selector para "elegir" el componente, no estoy seguro de que funcione asi, proba el siguiente codigo:

```
var urlAPI = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

    new Vue({
      el: 'body',
      created: function() {
        this.consultaAPI();
      },

      data: {
        personas: []
      },
      methods: {
        consultaAPI: function() {
          this.$http.get(urlAPI)
        .then(function(respuesta) {
          this.personas = respuesta.data.results;
        });
    }
  },
  components: {
    'personas': {
      props: ['lista'],
      template: '<ul v-for="persona in lista"><li>{{ persona.name}}</li></ul>',
    }
  }
});
```

Y en el html:

```
<body>
  <personas lista="personas">
  </personas>
  <pre>
    {{ personas | json}}
  </pre>
</body>
```

Los componentes te sirven para "extender" el html, pero tienen un par de características especiales, como one direction para enviar datos usando props y despues tenes que usar eventos para comunicarte con el parent.

Doc oficial: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Probá el codigo y fijate si anda, o si necesitas mas ayuda.

saludos!

Comment: Hola ya revise otra informacion y al parecer cuando le paso el results no funciona por lo que lo omiti y ya despliega los datos gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del method omiti el parametro result y ya despliega los datos:

```
  methods: {
    consultaAPI: function() {
      this.$http.get(urlAPI)
        .then(function(respuesta) {
          this.personas = respuesta.data;
        });
    }
  },
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]